# Is there anything like ActionScript 3's "with" keyword in JAVA?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, keyword

In switching from AS3 to JAVA I am finding there are a few minor niceties that I miss, one of them specifically being the [**with**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#with) keyword. 
Is there anything similar to this in JAVA (6 or less)?

I am parsing values out of an object and would rather write something like:

```
/** Example in AS3 **/
function FancyParsingContructorInAS3(values:Object):void { 
    with (values) { 
        this.x = x; // functionally equivalent to `this.x = values.x;`
        this.y = y; 
        this.width = width; 
        this.height = height; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: IMO you should move away from such "niceties" as it makes your code less readable.

Comment: and much, much more slower!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to two use cases for the `with` statement.

1) To change the value of `this` in a particular context

```
public class App {

     public void stuff() {
         //this refers to the current instance of App
         final Object obj = new Object();
         with(obj) {
         //this refers to obj
         }
     }
}
```

There is nothing like this in Java. You would just put the method code into the `Object`.

2) To import methods from another `class` so that they can be used unqualified.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(Math.max(Math.PI, 3));
}
```

Can be changed, in java with `import static`. This allows `static` members of another `class` to be imported into the current `class`. Adding the following three import statements:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import static java.lang.Math.max;
import static java.lang.Math.PI;
```

Would allow you to instead write

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    out.println(max(PI, 3));
}
```

You can see that is makes the code somewhat less readable however. It's not especially obvious where `out`, `max` and `PI` come from.

Comment: Wow, that's terrible, but fascinating!

Comment: Looks like `Kotlin` implemented this functionality to match how `Action Script` did.

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html

Comment: @Blake it’s more than Kotlin added extension functions - which allowed them to implement `with`. I don’t know how it works in ActionScript but in Kotlin `with` simply a utility method that executes a lambda as an extension function to the passed in object. In fact it’s one of 6 “scope functions” in Kotlin.